# Как реализовать клавиатуру?

Tags: xml, android, java

Появилась идея создать свое собственное виртуальное пианино для Android. Появился вопрос. Каким образом можно замостить так изображения клавиш пианино либо отлавливать их на одной картинке?

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое что мне представляется это четыре варианта:

1. Сделать каждую клавишу отдельной кнопкой и на каждую повесить обработчик клика. Плюс в том, что если картинка клавиши будет не сильно сложной графически (без сложных цветопереходов), то можно будет реализовать оную в ninepatch или в векторе и следовательно будет хорошая поддержка различных экранов. Минус в том, что придется делать слушатель клика на каждую клавишу.
2. Сделать клавиатуру отдельной картинкой и вычислять нажатую клавишу по пиксельным координатам/пропорциям экрана. Плюс в том, что слушатель будет один (и скорее всего со свитчем или if-else блоками) и не надо будет париться с разметкой - растянул картинку на весь экран и доволен. Минус в том, что будет картинка всей клавиатуры => больше по размеру, чем в предыдущем варианте и могут возникнуть некоторые проблемы с вычислениями областей где находится такая-то клавиша.
3. Можно сделать посредством OpenGL напрямую или с помощью либы инкапсулирующей ее (AndEngine советую многие для 2D графики). Плюс в том, что отрисовка графики и анимация будет офигенно быстрой. Минус в том, что не избавляемся от проблемы поддержки разных пропорций экрана и это решение очень трудоемко.
4. Можно с помощью WebView и какой-нибудь javascript либы (JQuery например) сделать клавиши и анимацию. Плюс в том, что если вы знаете джаваскрипт, то реализуете это достаточно быстро, к тому же есть различные фрэймворки (вроде JQueryMobile называется один из них) позволяющие сгенерить приложение обертку для javascript эээ... программы, и обертку можно сразу сгенерить под множество платформ. Минус с проблемами расположения областей где находятся клавиши (говорят бывают сдвинуты) и в том как прикручивать бэкэнд, лично я не представляю, ни разу ни с чем подобным не сталкивался.

P.S. Недавно читал статью где говорилось, что в андроиде время отклика интерфейса около 100мс и типо из-за этого невозможно сделать более-менее профессиональное ПО синтезирующее звук. Там говорилось, что у яблочников и оконщиков около 25мс время отклика. Но даже если и так то я думаю для программы для развлечения это не критично.

Comment: Интересует первый вариант, а точнее - как лучше всего разметкой это сделать. Ведь, как вы помните, между белыми клавишами рояля есть черные. И вообще. Как компоновать лучше всего изображения в подобных случаях. XML по моему не самый лучший выбор.

Comment: Можно с помощью LayoutInfater т.е. делаешь только разметку двух типов клавиш - черной и белой, затем уже в самом джавакоде хардкодишь окончательный вид пианино, если я не ошибаюсь, то нельзя нажать на ту часть кнопки, которая заслонена другой кнопкой, т.е. можно по сути забором вплотную друг к другу поставить белые клавиши, а поверх ни уже черные. Только в таком варианте прийдется помучаться с немного с черными и расстановкой их. Я бы сперва сделал банальной разметкой, просто и быстро и если не устроит производительность, то пробовал бы другие варианты. Ой вспомнил еще пару, допишу в ответ.

Comment: в первом варианте хватит одного обработчика, просто с блоками switch(view.getId()){   
 .....   
}